# Can we develop iot aplication by using .NET without using C and embedded C

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iot

I want to develop IOT application in .NET. but I don't know embedded C. Can we develop IOT application using .NET languages?

Is it necessary to learn embedded c, c and java web services?

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://www.netmf.com/gadgeteer/

It's all based on .Net

Comment: i dnt want to make electronic gadgets. i want to communicate with electronic devices like sensors and want to send data into cloud or server and anylse the data.like home automation. auto mobile automation

Comment: What kind of device should the app run on?

Comment: i want to develop the applications which can tell me whether fan is running or not in remote location via sms. such kind of things i need to develop, or else room temperature at other location.

Answer (score 1):

You can check also out this [Development with Windows 10](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot)

You can develop applications only using C# with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Do you need to write component-specific drivers, or are you planning to reuse components already programmed (that expose an API)? Do you want to provide a backend service for IoT devices, or do you want to program "the things"?
Anyway, I assume from your question that you are new to the topic, so I would say that until you reach the point of needing to write/compile C code you can develop and/or interface with most of the common prototyping boards via .NET.

You may have a look at the following links:

Arduino interfacing: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Csharp

Windows 10 IoT: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot

RaspberryPI.Net: https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net

Comment: i dnt want to create drivers, i just want to do applications like to analyse the electronic device behavior which is present at remote location. like house or office instruments. i want to send or store data some where and send details to someone...such kind of products

Comment: Then you can do all this without writing code in C. The devices you want to get data from are most probably already equipped with (or ready for being equipped with) a full network stack that allows you to send the data over the web. Your main effort would be to expose a web service and let the devices send data to it. If devices are sensors that have low or no access to power supply, I'd suggest to use simple UDP packets.

Your idea seems to be similar to Yaler.net (hope this is not against StackOverflow rules): https://yaler.net/ - this could give you an idea of what needs to be done.